# Is it possible to give a user defined color to a 'specific symbol' in vim?

Tags: linux, vim

I am working on a Grammar.txt file in vim editor.Is there a way I could give a different color to the '/', so that it is visually more appealing to my eyes.

A lot of my work requires working on paper, and differentiating keywords on screen this way would be helpful.

Here is a small snippet from my file

```
<Prog> ------ <functions><building>
<functions> ------ <function><functions>/ #
<function> ------ <funsig> <funcbody>
<funsig>------ <type>  id (<params>)
<type> ------ int/float/distance/<floortype>/point/wall/doors/window/ratio
<params>------ <type>id<LF1>/#
<LF1>---------comma<params>/#
<funcbody>----- {<stats>}
<stats>----- <stat> <stats>/ #
<stat>----- <assignmentstats>/<returnstats>/<declarativestats>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the `:match` command:

```
:match {color-group} /\//
```

You can get a list of color groups by using the `:highlight` command without any arguments.  Thus, something like this:

```
:match Function /\//
```

You can also clear any user-made matches by calling the `clearmatches` function.

```
:call clearmatches()
```

More help on these commands:

```
:help :match
:help :highlight
```

Answer (score 2):

Assumed you use search highlighting (`:set hlsearch`), just search for `/`:

```
/\/
```

Example:

[image: highlighting in vim]

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to complement @EvergreenTree's answer a bit.

Vim has this *highlighting* capability called *matching*, which indeed works like this:

```
:match Error /pat/
```

The first argument marks a highlight group, a list of which you can check out with `:hi`. The second argument is a regexp-powered search pattern that needs to be wrapped in `/` separators. In case of unclear patterns you usually test out the pattern by issuing traditional search. When the pattern looks fine, you can insert the last searched pattern in the `:match` line by typing `<C-r> /`. You can clear the highlights by calling `:match` alone, without arguments.

There are also commands `:2match` and `:3match` to highlight more different patterns simultaneously. These work similarly to `:match`.

If you need even more matches (happens easily with log file analysis), there's a set of VimL functions:

```
:call matchadd('Function', 'patt')
:call clearmatches()
```

This time the pattern doesn't need those `/` separators around it but otherwise the regexp syntax remains the same.